# Local network binding and routing

Tags: networking, routing, virtualhost

I have set up a local development environment on my laptop. It is based on Hyper-v and runs common LAMP stack on Ubuntu 18.04.

On my laptop, I have set the local hosts file to point to the site domain name (i.e. testsite.local) to the local ip address of this virtual machine, and therefore, I can access the test site on my laptop without any issues.

I want to access the same site using my home office computer using the same domain name. In other words, I want testsite.local on my home office computer to be routed to the virtual machine.

Are there any way to achieve this?

[image: Network Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a DNS server with forwarders (for internet related domains) so you can add your domain (*.local) and those will respond (as long as you configure the other machines to use your VM as DNS server as well).

I have found a great article where it explains how to use [DNSMasq](https://www.instructables.com/id/Running-your-own-DNSDHCP-Server-the-Easy-way/) it's not difficult and, if you see it works, perhaps move the configuration to a real, small machine so you can setup a more secure and robust home network.

I hope this can help you solve your issue.

Regards,

-JP

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out and see how it goes :D